# Form keeps redirecting

Tags: php, ajaxform

Keeps going to next page but I want it to print below the form box. Any ideas why this is happening?

```
              <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Enter">
              <div id="result"></div>
              <input type="submit" value="Submit">
              <!-- Placeholder where link is updated on success or an error message is shown -->
              <div id="result"></div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </body>



        <script> 
          $('#process_form').ajaxForm({ // Make sure the form doesn't redirect us.
            success: function(response) {
              // Update the link with the response.
              $('#result').html(response);
              $('#name').val('');
            }
          });
        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can solve this problem...

just use  this  **Elemetn.preventDefault()**

here your html code

```
<form action="" method="get"></form>
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Enter">
<div id="result"></div>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
<!-- Placeholder where link is updated on success or an error message is shown -->
</form>
```

here your js code

```
$('input[type="submit"]').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    var value = $('#name').val();
    $('#result').html(value)

});
```

Hope it will be work :)

Comment: Still refreshes to next page.

Comment: could you show me your full code?

Comment: I am not downvoting you, but you haven't understood the question, because it has not been explained properly.  Consequently, this is **Not an answer**